Portuguese with US-International keyboard with Ubuntu 24.04 LTS
Not actually a question but an answer: I searched a lot for an answer about how to use a US-International keyboard for other languages than English. All solutions I found involved AltGr and weird shortcuts, when they somewhat worked. Others solutions included adding a shady repository and install some files from there. Out of question.
What worked perfectly for me was to go to Settings>Regional Settings>Input Method. From there, I created a system layout as this:

Language: Any Language
Layout: A user-defined custom
Layout Variant: Default

I know, not intuitive, but it worked perfectly for me. I use a keyboard Logitech Wave, but I believe this should work for any US-International keyboard.

Please re-write this page as a question in the section you've currently used, and write your own answer in the Answer section below.  You can write & answer your own questions, but you should follow the site Q&A rules.

I am running ubuntu 24.04.1. When I go into: Settings -> System -> Region & language - I can't find the "International" (or "Intl.") option.
